# query attributes of latest child with sqlalchemy 2

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have the following situation (sqlalchemy==2.0.19):

An object (here user) has multiple data sets, as they need to be versioned. but for querying data, i am mostly interested in the current (aka latest) data and therefore query its attributes, when searching for a user by name.

```py
class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass


class UserData(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user_data'

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    created_at: Mapped[datetime] = mapped_column(DateTime(timezone=True), server_default=func.now())

    user_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey('user.id'))
    user: Mapped[User] = relationship(back_populates="datas")

    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column()


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    created_at: Mapped[datetime] = mapped_column(DateTime(timezone=True), server_default=func.now())

    datas: Mapped[list[UserData]] = relationship(
        back_populates="user", order_by="desc(UserData.created_at)"
    )


async def prep_user(session: Session, names: list[str]):
    user = User()
    session.add(user)
    session.commit()
    session.refresh(user)

    for name in names:
        account = UserData(user_id=user.id, name=name)
        session.add(account)
        session.commit()


async def main():
    engine = ...
    session = ...
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

    await prep_user(session=session, names=['user1', "user2"])

    user = session.query(User).first()
    print(user.user)
    print(user.datas)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

what i then want to do, is to query the latest dataset of the user for its attributes. (be aware that it might not have a dataset yet)
e.g.

```
# returns the user
user = session.query(User).filter(User.latest_data.name == "user2").first()
# returns None because the newest data has name "user2"
user = session.query(User).filter(User.latest_data.name == "user1").first()
```

i have a vague idea to solve it with `hybrid_attribute` or subqueries, but i am trying for hours and haven't solved it yet.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you targetting?

Comment: PostgreSQL, latest

Answer (score 0):

I found at least a working solution:

```
subquery = (session.query(UserData.user_id, func.max(UserData.created_at).label("latest_created_at"))
.group_by(UserData.project_id).subquery())

query = (session.query(User)
         .join(subquery, User.id == subquery.c.user_id)
         .join(UserData, UserData.user_id == subquery.c.user_id)
         .filter(UserData.created_at == subquery.c.latest_created_at)
        )
result = query.filter(UserData.name == "foo").first()
```

that query searches a user by name with the latest data set